# C# I have 50+ else if statements for cards, is there a way to make it shorter or do it all at one go?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a form that loads and generates 7 different random numbers, from 1-13, 1 being Ace, and 13 being King. After generating 7 different random numbers, it puts each of those random numbers into the 7 picture boxes. I'm displaying the picture boxes using the if statement.

It also cycles through an array of "Spades, Hearts, Clubs and Diamonds", 13 times.

And My if statements are like:

```
if (cardNum == 1 && cardType ==  "Spades")
{
    pictureBox1.Image = ace_of_spades;
}
else if (cardNum == 1 && cardType == "Hearts")
{
    pictureBox1.Image = ace_of_hearts;
}
else if (...)
{
    //change picture box
} //repeat it like 50 times
```

Is there a simple, easy way to pick 7 random cards and show them in the picture box?

It is extremely time consuming, the way I do it.

Comment: If you named your image resources like "Spades1, Hearts4" etc., you could load them by name via `cardType + cardNum`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So many non-OOP suggestions of how to handle this.  Here's my solution, which lets each object track itself, and will provide a simple way to shuffle the deck and get the image associated with each card (I've written a few card games).

For storing the actual images, embed them into your project as resource files, named in a specific way:

- card_Club_1
- card_Club_2
- card_Club_3
- etc...

Then, when you want a card image, you just combine the suit and value and request that resource name from the resource manager, as shown below.  This method requires a bit more setup and planning, but will give you *much* cleaner code.  You can even do all this in a separate project and then re-use the classes/resources by just referencing the DLL in the application where you want to have a deck of cards available.

```
enum Suit : uint
{
    Club = 0,
    Heart,
    Spade,
    Diamond
}
class Card
{
    public int
        Value;
    public Suit
        Suit;

    public System.Drawing.Image GetImage()
    {
        return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(
            global::cardLibraryProject.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream(string.Format("card_{0}_{1}", this.Suit, this.Value))
        );
    }
}
class Deck
{
    System.Collections.ArrayList
        _arr;

    private Deck()
    {
        this._arr = new System.Collections.ArrayList(52);
    }

    void Add(Card crd)
    {
        if (!this._arr.Contains(crd))
            this._arr.Add(crd);
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        System.Collections.ArrayList tmp1 = new System.Collections.ArrayList(this._arr);
        System.Collections.ArrayList tmp2 = new System.Collections.ArrayList(52);
        while (tmp1.Count > 0)
        {
            int idx = rnd.Next(tmp1.Count);
            tmp2.Add(tmp1[idx]);
            tmp1.RemoveAt(idx);
        }
        this._arr = tmp2;
        tmp1.Clear();
        tmp2.Clear();
    }

    public static Deck CreateDeck()
    {
        Deck newDeck = new Deck();
        for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
                newDeck.Add(new Card { Value = i, Suit = (Suit)s });
        return newDeck;
    }
}
class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Deck cards = Deck.CreateDeck();
        cards.Shuffle();

        pictureBox1.Image = cards[0].GetImage();
        // code to play game would go here.  Obviously, if you took
        // my suggestion about creating a "Cards" library, then you
        // wouldn't have a "void Main" at all, and this would
        // all go in the application that was the actual game.
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I type up this code in the Program.cs file or Form1.cs?

Comment: The classes (with the exception of "Program") can go wherever.  All of these are Types that would go inside a namespace.  How you implement using the "Deck" class would depend on what kind of application you're making.  This is just a high-level design for a series of classes to implement building something which needs a deck of cards.  Walking you through creating an entire application begining-to-end is a bit more involved.

Comment: Setup a setup of libraries to handle this sort of thing.  It also includes (the beginnings of) a base class to handle game logic.  There is also a separate project specifically for an "Uno" type game. https://github.com/tenshino/RainstormStudios/tree/6e4dcff8c9586c0869249d38ba7c00cf5f0c9bda/RainstormStudios.Games/Cards

Comment: Just FYI:  I mucked up my Git repo, so here's an updated link: https://github.com/tenshino/RainstormStudios/tree/master/RainstormStudios.Games/Cards

Comment: I know I accepted the answer late, but I got back to this project and ended up googling the same issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of ways, but in general I would say: **Use an array as a lookup**

For example, you have an array like

```
Image[] images = new[]
{
    ace_of_spades,
    ace_of_hearts,
    ...
};
```

Now all you have to do is calculate the right index. Since you didn't provide as much information as I need to help you on this, I will simply guess that it would look similar to this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = images[cardNum * 7 + (int)cardType];
```

Like I said, this is the idea behind this. Now you have to find the right calculation for it.

Comment: Your indexer is much better than mine.

Comment: Thanks! Well, your's randomizes the image, but I think the OP wants to randomize two numbers and find the right card by those two.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your items in to an array then use your random to pick a index from the array.

```
private Image[] _cards = new Image[] {ace_of_spades, ace_of_hearts, /* and so on for all of the cards*/ }

void YourFunction(Random rnd)
{
    var nextCardIndex = rnd.GetNext(_cards.Length);
    pictureBox1.Image = _cards[nextCardIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rename your images. If you could have names such as Spade_1, Spade_2, etc you could build up the file name in a simple step.

```
var name = cardType + "_" + cardNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to randomization from 0-51 (total 52 cards).

Then for the suit, the suit would be based on the INTEGER of card # / 13..  Thus cards 0-12 ex:Spades, 13-25=Hearts, 26-38 = Diamonds, 39-51 = Clubs.

The Modulus of the number 13 would be the card (from 0-12).  BY adding 1 to the modulus result, you would go from 0-12 as an array 0 = Ace, 12 = King